# Hovering Issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make the nav-link have the color of blue, with the hover effect having the color of dark-blue. I got the color right but when I try to use hover, it doesn't work. Does  anyone what the issue is? Also, does anyone know how to override bootstrap styles with my custom styles without making a mess. Thank You!

I have included the the necessary code down below, and thank you again for helping me solve this difficult issue of mine.

```css
:root {
    --white: #F9F7F7;
    --light-blue: #DBE2EF;
    --blue: #3F72AF;
    --dark-blue: #3F72AF;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
  color: var(--blue);
}

body {
    background: var(--white);
}

/* Navbar */
nav {
    background: var(--light-blue);
}

#brand, #link {
    color: var(--blue);
}

.nav-link.hover {
    color: var(--dark-blue) !important;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Links -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png" type="image/x-icon" />

<!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" id='brand' href="#">Amodh Dhakal</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" id='link'>Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" id='link'>Project</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" id='link'>Contact</a>
          </li>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's two things. The blue and dark blue have the same hex values, so you'll want to change those to whichever values you'd like:

```
:root {
    --white: #F9F7F7;
    --light-blue: #DBE2EF;
    --blue: blue;
    --dark-blue: darkblue; 
}
```

And I noticed you used .hover instead of :hover, so you'll want to change your css hover effect to this:

```
.nav-link:hover {
    color: var(--dark-blue) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

`blue` and `dark-blue` are the same color; try changing one of them:

```
:root {
    --white: #F9F7F7;
    --light-blue: #DBE2EF;
    --blue: #3384e5;//<-- changed this
    --dark-blue: #3F72AF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the color values in your root

```
:root {
    --white: #F9F7F7;
    --light-blue: #DBE2EF;
    --blue: #3F72AF; <- Same values
    --dark-blue: #3F72AF; <- Same values
}
```

And change

```
.nav-link.hover {
    color: var(--dark-blue) !important;
}
```

To

```
.nav-link:hover {
    color: var(--dark-blue) !important;
}
```